# How to export a excel file using php script

Tags: php, arrays, excel

I am exporting a excel sheet using php script and my code is

```
<?php
    function excel_file(){     
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"demo.xls\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    $out = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($tabledata as $data)
    {
        fputcsv($out, $data,"\t");
    }
    fclose($out);
      } 
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" name="excel_file" onclick="<?php excel_file(); ?>" value="Download File">
```

Problem is this:

1. This `function excel_file()` execute on loading the page not on click.
2. The excel file which i get, includes the data of whole page not the data of  that perticular array "`$tabledata`"

Comment: `$tabledata` isn't available in the scope of your `excel_file()` function, and you need to suppress outputting your html markup if you're outputting the CSV

Comment: i am not getting your 2nd point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You include in your button the output of the function. You cannot combine a javascript onclick with a php function.

HTML:

```
<a href="your_url.php?action=xls">Excel</a>
```

Then in your code

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'xls')
{
  excel_file();
  exit;
}
```

In this way you click on the Excel link and send that action to the server.
You catch with PHP the `$_GET['action']` and call the `excel_file()` function.

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't see the error here or I am really confused on the moment.. Please clarify the error you see.

Comment: in my case now its working... i am using <form name="form_name" method="post" action=""><input type="submit" value="Download Excel" name ="submit" /></form>  .. as my php code is on same page :)

Comment: @Stefan - there's always days like that :)

Comment: This would bring up the prompt to download? /* that is the reason I am viewing this question */

Comment: Also, is there a way to POST to that URL, instead of using query string?

Comment: @MikeWarren Yes, By using a form with method=post or a javascript equivalent code